# Click on element from a dropdown menu in cypress only if checked

Tags: javascript, html, automation, cypress

I have the following html code with several elements in a dropdown menu. I only want to click on an item if it is selected (has the class selected) or, as you can see [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I29Cf.jpg) in printscreen, it has that check mark in front of the name. How can I do this with IF in cypress?

I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```js
clickOnDropdown(name: string){
  cy.get('#SelectedPractitionersIds').parent().click(); // #SelectedPractitionersIds is the id for dropdown
  cy.get('.selected').contains(name).then(($button) => { // ".selected" it is a class which appears only when the item is checked and selected
  if ($button.hasClass('check-mark')) {
    cy.get('.selected').contains(name).parent().click();
  } 
});
```

And calling from test like `clickOnDropdown('PPNCFPCCPE PPNCFPCCPE')`

```
<div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 205.2px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 0px;">
   <ul class="dropdown-menu inner selectpicker" role="menu" style="max-height: 193.2px; overflow-y: auto;">
      <li rel="0" class=""><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text"> PPNCFPCCPE  PPNCFPCCPE</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
      <li rel="1" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">alex pract2</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
      <li rel="2" class="selected"><a tabindex="0" class="" style=""><span class="text">ppncfpccpe2 ppncfpccpe2</span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-ok check-mark"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I hope I have provided all the essential details

Answer (score 2):

The `check-mark` class you seek is on a descendent of $button, so use `.find('.check-mark')` in your `if()` condition.

Unlike `.contains()` which can search for text in all descendants, `.hasClass()` only looks at the current element.

```js
const name = "alex pract2";

cy.get(".selected")
  .contains(name)
  .then(($button) => {

    if ($button.find('.check-mark').length) {

      cy.get(".selected").contains(name).parent().click();
      
      //or just
      $button.click()

    }
  });
```

Comment: I have this error: " Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find content: 'PPNCFPCCPE' within the element: [ <li.selected>, 3 more... ] but never did."  This error occurs when the item is unchecked (no class selected). If it is checked, then it is intervened and the code is clicked and works.

Comment: That's why I used "alex pract2" - it has the selected class but "PPNCFPCCPE" does not.

Comment: Look at your code comment ***// ".selected" it is a class which appears only when the item is checked and selected***

Comment: If selected is not actually a criteria, don't use it in `cy.get(".selected")`. Use `cy.get("li")`.

Comment: I may not have expressed myself correctly. I actually want that when it doesn't have a .selected class and automatically it doesn't have a check mark class to go the code further and get over it. In fact, for this I want to use that IF, to check if I have the selected class and check mark present in the element. The IF must be valid for any item on the list, which either has a check mark or does not. Only if it is present, the element should be pressed. If not, skip it

Comment: I get the same error if I use cy.get("li")

Comment: If you are dropping the `.selected` class then use `cy.contains('li', name)`. But it seems that `.selected` must factor in somehow - you need to clarify.